# C# Close a form in panel and open a new form in the same panel

Tags: c#, winforms

There are two forms MainForm and HomePageForm. The HomePageForm is inside the panel of MainForm. The HomePage Form has a login button. On clicking the login button, I want to close the HomePageForm and Open the LoginForm inside the same panel.

MainForm.cs

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Homepage homepage = new Homepage()
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        TopLevel = false,
        TopMost = true
    };
    showForm(homepage);         
}

public void showForm(Form form)
{
    mainPanel.Controls.Add(form);
    form.Show();
}
```

Homepage.cs

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    f1.ShowDialog();

    this.Hide();
    LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm()
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        TopLevel = false,
        TopMost = true
    };
    MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
    mainForm.showForm(loginForm);
}
```

This closes the HomePage form but does not opens the Login Form.

Comment: You cannot do this: `MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();`. You're creating a new Instance of `MainForm` that is not related to the existing Instance. Your could use `Homepage.Parent` and add the new Form to this instance of your Panel (or `Homepage.Parent.FindForm()`). -- You shouldn't be using Forms but UserControls.

Comment: What you are doing is correct.  You just didn't do the equivalent with loginForm that you did with HomePage.  You are missing : mainPanel.Controls.Add(loginForm);

Comment: @jdweng The first chunk of code is run from MainForm, so the `mainPanel` instance is available. The second chunk is run from `Homepage`, which doesn't know anything about a `mainPanel` (even though it's simply its Parent). That's why the OP is trying to call a public method of MainForm; unfortunately, by creating a new instance of it.

Comment: Probably simpler is to add a reference to the calling MainForm in the constructor of Homepage, then use this reference to call showForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create an instance of the `MainForm` class and call its method, but you must use the existing instance. To use open forms, you must find the form with the name of the program.

Change `Login_Click` to :

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    f1.ShowDialog();

    this.Hide();
    LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm()
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        TopLevel = false,
        TopMost = true
    };
    MainForm mainForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<MainForm>().Where(x => x.Name == "mainFormName").FirstOrDefault();
    mainForm.showForm(loginForm);
}
```

In the line `Where(x => x.Name == "mainFormName")` put the form name instead of mainFormName.